# if I got from anyone reference like #!foo=32 what I would recieve if Ia got JS on/off

Tags: jquery, seo, href

Guyz! I couldn't find the answer to the question what if I got from anyone reference like

```
    ..#!foo=32
```

from

```
    <a href=..?foo=32 onClick=" navigate(..#!foo=32); return false;">click</a>
```

what I would receive if I got my **JS**:

1. On
2. Off

I'm trying to connect it with SEO. It seems to me that if everyone who goes to link like

```
 ..#!foo=32
```

will develop this link that robots don't see, but not link like

```
  href=...?foo=32
```

which is actually needed for **SEO**.

I'm very sorry If I repeat someone's question, but really couldn't find a clear answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hashbang (#!) is a system Google proposed to solve the issue of Ajax based dynamic pages. Google and Bing currently support it.

I'm sure Googling hashbang will get you to the details.

Comment: thank you very much vor your time and efforts, I read a lot of articles about it and I got the point. Honestly reading more about using history.js.

Comment: PushState and what it lets you do is a better solution and probably quite well supported.